# Editing Bundle extras and saving it

Tags: java, android

So I have a situation where I populate TextView from Intent extras and then allow users to edit it. When user taps on edit Button, EditText appears with text shown in TextView.

Then user can input new value.

And finally when the save Button is pressed, new value isn't saving, instead the old value is still shown.

Here's my code:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            textViewNazivTodoaDetails.setText(extras.getString("naslov"));
            textViewDatumTodoaDetails.setText(extras.getString("datum"));
            final int id = extras.getInt("id");

            String oldText = extras.getString("naslov");
            editTextDetaljnoIspravljanje.setText(oldText);
        }

        final String newText = editTextDetaljnoIspravljanje.getText().toString();

        buttonDetaljnoIspravljanjeDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textViewNazivTodoaDetails.setText(newText);
            }
        });


    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put the line __String newText = editTextDetaljnoIspravljanje.getText().toString();__ inside the onClickListener

Answer (score 1):

You are clearly setting the text back to old text inside your `onClick` with the following line.

```
textViewNazivTodoaDetails.setText(newText);
```

You don't need this line inside `onClick`. Instead of this you should have the code to save the new value to where ever you want to save it.

The line of code where you initialized `newText` was called before you edited it and contains the same value as `oldText`. Hence you see the old text again.

Your text view already has the newly entered text.